# Angular No provider for when using main module and 2 sub modules

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-providers

I have three modules, a compositon module, an auth module and a recordrequestmodule. The recordrequest module needs to use the ValuesService as a singleton. I am in the auth service using for root to return a module with providers and in the providers declaring the ValuesService. Then in the CompositionModule I am importing the AuthModule.forRoot(). This should import the ValuesService in the DI tree and be available to the recordsrequestmodule. Instead I am seeing 'No provider for ValuesService!'

Could someone check and see if they can spot an error in the code. I can include other parts if needed.

Composition Module

```
NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    HttpInterceptorModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    PubSubModule.forRoot(),
    RecordRequestQueueModule
],
providers:
[
    SecurityService,
    RoleGaurd
],
declarations: [
    AuthComponent,
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    RoutingRedirectComponent,
    HomeComponent
],
bootstrap:
[
    AppComponent
]
})
export class CompositionModule {
}
```

Record Request Queue Module

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    AuthModule,
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(recordRequestQueueRoutes)
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: [
    RecordRequestingQueueComponent,
    RecordRequestingWorkItem,
    RecordRequestingQueueSection
],
providers: [
    QueueClient
]
})

export class RecordRequestQueueModule {
constructor(valuesService: ValuesService) {
    console.log("Record Request Queue loaded.");
}
}
```

Auth Module

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule
],
declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent],
providers: [
    LoginClient
],
exports: [
    LogoutComponent,
    LoginComponent
]
})
export class AuthModule {
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: AuthModule,
        providers: [ValuesService]
    };
}
constructor() {
    console.log("Auth module loaded");
}
}
```

ValuesService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ValuesService {
public username: string;
}
```

Comment: It should work. Check https://plnkr.co/edit/GXj05FW2Q9LsAVN2ZzWG?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction?

Comment: Assuming @yurzui is right and the code really does all work, then are you sure that all of the definition/.js files themselves are loaded?
Fwiw, I've also seen this error when Angular and the code know the name of a service or provider, but I'd forgotten to actually load the file in my index page...

Comment: I am using webpack to load the files and can confirm that injecting the ValuesService into the composition module constructor does work its only when I try and inject it into one of the modules that composition service imports that it fails. This would lead me to believe that all the files are being loaded. I have also added a breakpoint in the forroot call in the authmodule and confirm it is being hit. I will make a plunker to reproduce if possible.